# Unable to install some AndroidSDK components [Error: The Following SDK Components were not installed]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I am trying to install the Android SDK to build my unity games onto this platform but I am unable to do so because of this error (Screenshot attached) that appears every single time I try to install it.
I searched for fixes on Google and Stack Overflow before posting and nothing I found worked for me.

Check list:

- Running as admin (failed)
- Running as .bat and admin (failed)
- reinstalling Android studio (failed)
  re-downloading installer (failed)
- [Not recommended] I did a PC Reset wiped every driver and all files and still this problem did not go away. (Failed)

I have no idea what to do anymore.

The Error:
[image: The Error]

Log:
[image: Log]

Comment: `Tag mismatch` sounds like a bug. Try not downloading the newest SDK components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/issues/88)
to see others who have had tag mismatch errors. Some have suggested it is a connection issue. (Meaning you should try changing the dns server to the public google one of 8.8.8.8 OR 8.8.4.4) It could be an ISP thing as well. You can also try a manual download from [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download)

Although, you may have to add maven support as Google is no longer supporting downloading of libraries through the SDK manager. Check out Google's page on [Support Library Setup](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup) for more details.

Comment: Indeed it was a connection issue. Changing the dns server helped. Although I still got a tag mismatch at the end, when I looked into the sdk manager everything was installed correctly so I think it fixed itself.

Comment: Glad I could help, but could you be more specific? How exactly did it fix itself? Was it after you switched your DNS or connecting to another network? How did the install process work for you that eventually resulted in the sdk manager installing correctly yet still resulting in a mismatch tag?

Comment: Sure. After I read you comment the first thing I did was google how to correctly change the dns server, which led me to a video on youtube showing how to exactly do it. Then right after I watched the video I did as instructed and changed my server to the first one you mentioned. WITH ANDROID STUDIO UNINSTALLED, I redownloaded the installer and did the setup. At the end I got a tag mismatch error. I clicked to open android studio regardless and went to the sdk manager there I found out everything had been installed correctly. I did nothing to prompt android studio to fix the error.